# how to build nativescript-vue .apk without submitting it to google store to share with my friends for beta testing

Tags: command-line-interface, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I see a lot of them in relating topics all involved in submitting to google store.    Is it possible to create .apk locally (CLI) so I can share this with few other friends? I'm using Nativescript Vue and I don't want to deal with Google store or Itune at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the articles you must have read should already cover building a APK, you stop it one step before you if you don't want to submit it to Google Play.

The [tns build](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps#build-signed-release-apk) command should give you the APK, you may just share it with your friends to try it. But remember they must have enabled unknown source in their settings so they can install the APK from anywhere.

If you are looking for a more organised way of distributing your Beta, Google Play itself has a option to invite people by email ids for beta testing, it won't be available for others until you release it. There are third parties too like Hockey App, TestFairy and more

Comment: Thanks..question...I did read the article but when I see things like --key-store...   I thought that had to do with putting the app into Google app store which I don't want to do now.   Do I still need to do this and have the option of not putting this app in the app marketplace?

Comment: Yes, you should sign your app. It's more like a digital signature for your app.