# sharing Nativescript prototype with team

Tags: nativescript

I am working on a prototype with NativeScript.  I have a distributed team, that uses both iPhone and Android, none of them technically proficient.  Is there anyway to share my app with them, without going thru the different app stores?

I thought perhaps I could upload to Playground, but that functionality doesn't seem to exist.
The QRC functionality seems promising, but I do no see how to share that with my team scattered across the country.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to build nativescript-vue .apk without submitting it to google store to share with my friends for beta testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606658/how-to-build-nativescript-vue-apk-without-submitting-it-to-google-store-to-shar)

Comment: not quite a duplicate question - I am not wanting to put my app into Apple or Google store at all.

Comment: Read it fully please, you don't have to. The question is about without submitting to stores.

Comment: yes, it looks like that article explains how to build a APK for Google,  but my question is how to share this with Google AND Apple.  The nativescript documents make no mention of how to share with iOS devices without going thru App Store.

Comment: Did you still read it fully? Did you notice about Hockey App, TestFairy etc.,? Those are third parties where you can upload the builds, allow access to whomever you like by email ids and let them install. {N} will not document about these as it's up to you to choose a third party or even build your own distribution system once you have the IPA / APK.

Comment: I see what you mean, I thought those were specific to Google and it didn't cross my mind to look at testing platforms to distribute a demo.  I will investigate that avenue.  Thank you for your patience!